# FETCH JOIN maximum depth?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

W was trying to fetch join over three levels:

```
JOIN FETCH entity1.collection1.collection2  // two OneToMany relations
```

but got:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: [...]
```

**Is it because it was too deep, or because a collection of collections cannot be fetched this way?** My max fetch depth is 3, if this is relevant.

I can, at the same time, do a triple JOIN FETCH starting from the other side:

```
JOIN FETCH entity3.entity2.entity1  // two ManyToOne relations
```

Somehow I cannot find anything in JPA specification, or in Hibernate docs, that would limit the depth of this clause.

Comment: Please include the message of the exception. Usually, it tells the reason of the error.

Comment: There's really nothing to present; the stack trace is cut by Glassfish, the topmost exception is "Unable to build EntityManagerFactory", caused by the exception I quoted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collection1` is of type `Collection`. And a `Collection` doesn't have a `collection2` field. That's how I reason about those kind of queries.

You must the create an explicit join over the collection:

```
select e from Entity1 e
left join fetch e.collection1 as c1
left join fetch c1.collection2 as c2
```

Note that this will produce a cartesian product, and thus petentially returns a huge number of rows. Also note that it will only be possible if one of the two collections at least is a set. If they're both bags, Hibernate will throw an exception when executing the query.

Comment: But collection2 is not referred to from the Entity1; it's one of Collection1 fields: `List<Collection2> collection2`. Hence the query is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think you can do a join fetch with an alias, so either `left join fetch e.collection1` or `left join e.collection1 as c1`.