# join fetch depth of inititialisation

Tags: hibernate

`from Item item left join fetch item.bids where item.description like '%gc%`'

The above will *fetch Items with its Bids initialized*. Supposed Bids owns 2-3 other collections B, C and D (And maybe B owns a couple more collections ?). Are the latter initialized as well? I was looking at [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393987/fetch-join-maximum-depth) and was wondering if its nessecary to join all the way to the last collection  or is it enough just the first join?(Assume that "Lazy" is used all the way)

Answer (score 0):

When we assume "Lazy" all the way.... it won't load all the collections chain unless you join it